# How to FTP a single file to an Azure .NET Core Website

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ftp

I've developed a .NET Core Website and published it to Azure.  Under the **wwwroot** folder, I have a **home** folder and within that folder I have a **home.txt** file.

I want a **none-developer** to be able to ftp their own copy of home.txt to my site and overwrite the one that is there.  They won't be doing this very often, but they will be doing it many times.

What is the easiest way for me to set this up for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to provide FTP access to a single file. So you probably have to write a `REST` endpoint that allows you to upload a file to your **wwwroot** folder and add an upload form to your web site for your "non-developer" users.

You could also create a *storage account* with multiple containers (one for each "non-developer"). Then you create a SAS (shared access signature) for each container and give it to your users. They can then upload their files using e. g. **Azure Storage Explorer**. To get the files into your website wwwwroot folder, you can write an Azure Function that gets triggered by azure function blob storage events.

Comment: Ahh, so write a console app that calls the restful API , sends the text file and that replaces the one on my site.  Sounds like a perfect solution.  I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: I already had a Web API, just never thought of this option.  I got it all working.  Thanks.  Marked as answer (first paragraph).